# What is the best way to store icon drawables?

Tags: android

What is the best way to store an app icon drawable? Is it recommended to store them in an SQL database or there is a better way to do it.
I will get my drawables from [getApplicationIcon(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationIcon(java.lang.String)).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to store that?  It's already stored in the APK that you fetched it from using that API.

Comment: Your are right, i don't need to store it. I should only store the package name of it. Thanks.